# Сколько раз можно редактировать свой коментарий, ответ и вопрос?

Tags: поддержка, правки, комментарии, ответы

Хотел бы узнать сколько раз можно редактировать свой коментарий, ответ и вопрос?

Comment: По ограничения на *количество* редактирований не слышал, но есть ограничение по времени для редактирования комментария

Comment: @АндрейNOP Расскажите подробнее про этот таймаут.

Comment: @edcft Подробнee: 5 мин.

Comment: Понял спасибо)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Количество редактирований не ограничено.
2. Автор может редактировать комментарий только первые 5 минут. Все правки записываются в историю. Модератор может редактировать любой комментарий в любое время.
3. После каждого редактирования сообщения есть grace period в 5 минут, который позволяет править сообщение несколько раз при условии отсутствия в это время комментариев и правок других участников.
4. Если два участника попеременно делают правки или откаты, может сработать тревога о войне правок, которую обработает модератор.
5. Если сообщение правится слишком много раз (кажется, 10 или 20), срабатывает тревога о большом числе правок, которую тоже обработает модератор.